# Not able to install Glassfish Tools in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I tried installing the Glassfish tools (Glassfish adapter) in Eclipse but got the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: GlassFish Tools 8.4.0.201510191754
>   (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group 8.4.0.201510191754)
>   Software currently installed: GlassFish Tools 8.3.0.201508262046
>   (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group 8.3.0.201508262046)
>   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       GlassFish Tools UI 8.3.0.201508262046 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui 8.3.0.201508262046)
>       GlassFish Tools UI 8.4.0.201510191754 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui 8.4.0.201510191754)   Cannot
>   satisfy dependency:
>       From: GlassFish Tools 8.3.0.201508262046 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group 8.3.0.201508262046)
>       To: oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui [8.3.0.201508262046]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: GlassFish Tools 8.4.0.201510191754 (oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.feature.group 8.4.0.201510191754)
>       To: oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui [8.4.0.201510191754]

Would anybody please help me on this?

Comment: Looks like it's already installed, to me. Have you tried just checking for updates?

Comment: It is saying that GlassFish Tools 8.3 is already installed and that you can't install 8.4 as well.

Comment: yes i saw that and removed the oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.ui 8.3.0.201508262046 from the features directory .. But still there was no effect in the installation .. may be the eclipse cache was creating some problem .. so extracted the whole eclipse directory once more<ya i m stupid should have used -clean option later realised it>